# Webdeploy on Windows Server 2022 with ASP.net core .net 5 locks files, even with EnableMsDeployAppOffline=true

Tags: .net, iis, locking, webdeploy

Our .Net5 Core application has moved from Windows Server 2019 to Windows Server 2022, we have deployed our application to ISS (v10.0.20348.1).

We deploy our application using webdeploy, our deployment settings are below.

```
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
        <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
        <PublishProvider>AzureVirtualMachine</PublishProvider>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://[oursite.com]</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <MSDeployServiceURL>[our delployment url]</MSDeployServiceURL>
        <DeployIisAppPath>[Our IIS PathName]</DeployIisAppPath>
        <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
        <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
        <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
        <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
        <UserName>ourusername</UserName>
        <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
        <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

When we deploy I can see the App_offline.htm file being placed in the app path correctly, this should, theoretically, shut down the app and allow us to deploy, however we get errors when we deploy, errors like this:

```
Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy cannot modify the file '[OurApp].dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.
```

We are deploying from Visual Studio 2022.

It seems really odd. I have even noticed that I can stop the App Pool and Website on IIS and it will not deploy successfully first time, getting the same locking message, but if we try 3 or 4 times, it will eventually work.

I understand the [shadowcopy functionality](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2021/07/19/aspnetcore6-shaddow-copy-iis.html) is only available in . Net6, so this is not an option.

I am trying to understand what we can change to make the webdeployments work consistently on IIS 10. Is there a feature of IIS we need to install or something similar?

Comment: When deploy the application, you need to open task manager and find the w3wp.exe, close it firstly. Then files won't be locked.

Comment: Closing w3wp.exe does not solve the problem of being able to deploy automatically via WebDeploy.

Comment: What about stop IIS before deploy? Use command line `net stop WAS` to stop IIS and `net start W3SVC` to start.